# Allow embedding the top-bar in external pages

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I've created a personal home page which aggregates the things I'm interested in (since Google killed iGoogle). This includes my flair but I would really like to have the stack-exchange top bar with its notifications. 
I tried adding an `iframe` with stackoverflow.com as its `src` but this doesn't work, apparently it requires being the top document.

My request is to have a way to add a stack-exchange top-bar to other sites.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think we'll support this for a variety of reasons.

- It makes it seem like you have an official site that's part of the network, that's surely a source of confusion.
- We'd have to open cross-site scripting possibilities and lowering our framing guards
- An `<iframe>` doesn't work unless the dropdowns could escape anyway, this breaks in most browsers (as it should)
- People *think* they're logged into your website, or we'd have to actually open global auth to everyone (again a *huge* security hole)

There are other reasons not to do this, but those are the blockers off the top of my head.  Note that you can however [use the API](https://api.stackexchange.com), specifically [the inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox) to fetch the data you're after and render it in the page.